# About what level should I be before picking a fight with a bear?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that enemies level up with you, but at which level does it become more of a fair fight? I'm currently a Level 10 Khajiit, so I haven't gotten too far into the game quite yet.

Answer (score 3):

Level isn't a very good indicator of capability.  Against a physical opponent like a bear, armor rating can mean the difference.  I think you should have about 125 armor rating before challenging bears.

Some ways to get more armor rating:

- Equip a shield.
- Upgrade your armor at a bench.
- If you've upgraded your armor and have gotten some blacksmithing skill since, upgrade it again.
- Use the alteration spell - Oakflesh.
- Raise your armor skill, train it if you have to.
- Get the armor perks, especially the 5 pointer at the root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to deal with a bear is with a sneak attack by a bow. If you have the perk deadly aim (archery sneak shot three times dmg) it is even easier. If you do this it does not matter what level you are on. I took down a snow bear level 5